# Kotlin Direct Access XML Error on clicking ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the current working code, which add

```
mNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation)
mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout)

val headerview : View = mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0)

mSettingsIcon = headerview.findViewById(R.id.settingsIcon)

mSettingsIcon.setOnClickListener {
    // navigate other activity
}
```

I want to replace it using direct XML access that is available on Kotlin.

I tried the following:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.navigation_header.*

mSettingsIcon.setOnClickListener {
    // Handle Click
}
```

But I received the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.my.app/com.my.app.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference (...) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference

I think that is because the ImageView Settings is located inside another XML (called Navigation Header) that is on XML like this:

inside activity_main.xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/mNavigationTab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:menu="@layout/navigation_items"/>
```

inside navigation_header.xml:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/mSettingsIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_settings"
    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
    android:padding="0dp"/>
```

Does anyone knows how can I access using Kotlin direct access to XML components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**At first,** You have to get `HeaderView` from `NavigationView` and then use below code to achieve this:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.navigation_header.view.*
```

---

```
val headerView = mNavigationTab.getHeaderView(0)

headerView.mSettingsIcon.setOnClickListener {
    // Handle Click
}
```